# TextView handling lots of characters in Swift

Tags: swift, performance, textview

I'm working on an app that contains a textView and some buttons, it does some calculations based on the cursor position. It contains for loops and arrays and a String extension to get the character after/before the curser and adds or remove from it. It runs smoothly with 500 characters or less, but more than that it starts to become slow in adding to or removing from the textView, and with more than a 1000 characters it becomes unbearable to work with. I've tested it with an iPhone 6s Plus and iPad Pro 2nd 12inch, and in the Xcode simulator, it acts exactly the same with all of these devises, so I don't think it is a hardware limitation.

Here are some examples of the code:

```
func checkLetter () {

    let nextOne = textView.text.unicodeScalars[getCursorPosition()]
    let nextTwo = textView.text.unicodeScalars[getCursorPosition()+1]
    let nextThree = textView.text.unicodeScalars[getCursorPosition()+2]
    let testLetter = ["ّ","ْ","ٌ","ُ","ٍ","ِ","ً","َ"]

    for b in 0...7 {
        if nextThree == testLetter[b] && nextTwo == "ّ" {
            print ("Next Three!")
            nextChar()
            nextChar()
            delLetter()
            delLetter()
            preChar()
        }else if nextThree == testLetter[b] && nextTwo == testLetter[b] {
            print ("Next Three!")
            nextChar()
            nextChar()
            nextChar()
            delLetter()
            delLetter()
            preChar()
        }else if nextTwo == testLetter[b] {
            print ("Next Two!")
            nextChar()
            nextChar()
            delLetter()
            preChar()
        }else if nextOne == testLetter[b] {
            print ("Next One!")
            nextChar()
            delLetter()
            preChar()
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
func preChar () {

    // only if there is a currently selected range
    if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange {

        // and only if the new position is valid
        if let newPosition = textView.position(from: selectedRange.start, offset: -1) {

            // set the new position
            textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)

        } 
    }
}
```

.

```
    func skipSpace () {
    for _ in  spaceCount...textView.text.count {
        if checkSpace() == false {
            nextChar()
        }
    }
}
```

The Extension I'm using

```
extension String.UnicodeScalarView {

var length: Int {
    return count
}

subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return self[i ..< i + 1]
}

func substring(fromIndex: Int) -> String {
    return self[Swift.min(fromIndex, length) ..< length]
}

func substring(toIndex: Int) -> String {
    return self[0 ..< Swift.max(0, toIndex)]
}

subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: Swift.max(0, Swift.min(length, r.lowerBound)),
                                        upper: Swift.min(length, Swift.max(0, r.upperBound))))
    let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
    let end = index(start, offsetBy: range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
    return String(self[start ..< end])
  }  
}
```

Then these functions and others are called when a button is clicked.

Please help if you know how may I improve the speed.

Comment: Next time please [edit your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270233/textview-handling-lots-of-characters-in-swift) rather than reposting.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve deleted the previous post because I knew it would take me sometime to get my code examples, and it is useless to keep the post for so long without any examples, so I decided to delete it instead. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Start by using Instruments and see which line(s) of code are actually causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve fixed it and it’s much faster now. It was the skipSpace() method.

```
func skipSpace () {
for _ in  spaceCount...textView.text.count {
    if checkSpace() == false {
        nextChar()
    }
}
```

When I type lots of text this loop range gets huge (spaceCount...textView.text.count) because it gets the number of characters in the textView, so it was simply to change it to a fixed number like:  (spaceCount...50), and that’s it!

Thanks